# WCF Read data issue from service

Tags: wcf, xml-serialization, entity-framework-4.1

I am tying to get the generic List of user `List<User>` object from my web service to my web application. probably this is common issue. i searched a lot but got different remedies with each link. so finally i decide to ask to chaps over here... anyways

I am using console application for fetching the data from my hosted wcf web service. where as my WCf web service having the Entity framework 4.1. am using objects from its model class. when i tried to add service reference to my web application , it typically generates the proxy in web app. i am able to post data means i could create user. but while `getusers` which is returning List , getting following exceptions...:

> Exception:
>   An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to
>   http://myserver/AdminService/MyAdminService.svc. This could be due to
>   the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could
>   also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server
>   (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more
>   details.
>
> Inner Exception is :
>   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred
>   on a receive
>
> and inner-inner exception is :  Unable to read data from the
>   transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by
>   the remote host.
>
> with message : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host
>   Error Code  :10054
>
> Where as Event log saying :
>   A message was not logged.
>   Exception: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was
>   an error while trying to serialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:getUsersResult. The InnerException message was
>   'Type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.User_00DEC686D7E21DB0D84B595F647A03FFB4943938F76E8C3DBBE0F77F8BC29A1D'
>   with data contract name
>   'User_00DEC686D7E21DB0D84B595F647A03FFB4943938F76E8C3DBBE0F77F8BC29A1D:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any
>   types not known statically to the list of known types - for example,
>   by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the
>   list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see
>   InnerException for more details. --->
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.User_00DEC686D7E21DB0D84B595F647A03FFB4943938F76E8C3DBBE0F77F8BC29A1D'
>   with data contract name
>   'User_00DEC686D7E21DB0D84B595F647A03FFB4943938F76E8C3DBBE0F77F8BC29A1D:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any
>   types not known statically to the list of known types - for example,
>   by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the
>   list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
>          at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract
>   dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean
>   verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type
>   declaredType)
>          at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type
>   objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle
>   declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
>          at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType,
>   Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
>          at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType,
>   Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
>          at WriteArrayOfUserToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object ,
>   XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
>          at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
>          at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator
>   writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
>          at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator
>   writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
>          at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator
>   writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
>          at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter
>   writer, Object graph)
>          at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryWriter
>   writer, PartInfo part, Object graph)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryWriter
>   writer, PartInfo part, Object graph)
>          at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameter(XmlDictionaryWriter
>   writer, PartInfo part, Object graph)
>          at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeBody(XmlDictionaryWriter
>   writer, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription
>   messageDescription, Object returnValue, Object[] parameters, Boolean
>   isRequest)
>          at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.OperationFormatterMessage.OperationFormatterBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter
>   writer)
>          at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriter.WriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter
>   writer)
>          at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.ToString(XmlDictionaryWriter
>   writer)
>          at
>   System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.MessageLogTraceRecord.WriteTo(XmlWriter
>   writer)
>          at
>   System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.MessageLogger.LogInternal(MessageLogTraceRecord
>   record)
>          at
>   System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.MessageLogger.LogMessageImpl(Message&
>   message, XmlReader reader, MessageLoggingSource source)
>          at
>   System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.MessageLogger.LogMessage(Message&
>   message, XmlReader reader, MessageLoggingSource source)
>        Process Name: w3wp
>        Process ID: 5928

What should be this issue. me and team searching for this since 3 days. but unfortunately not overcome so far...

I tried lot of stuffs like add serializable attribute, endpoint modifications ... i can not recollect all :) ... probably you may give us right directions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that EF classes are by default proxied at runtime to support lazy loading and dynamic change tracking. So you don't serialize `User` class but class derived from `User` at runtime. WCF doesn't like that. Turn off proxy creation on your context.

```
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Thanksk for sharing concept ....this concept is really new for me...where i have to put this line ?

Comment: I don't know how, but this helped me right now, thank you!